# Proper method to write hibernate functions

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate in my project and it is well going, but my problem is i am little bit confused that is i am going good way for writing hibernate functions. Below i paste my block of code to understand how i had written the hibernate functions please check it and tell me whther it is a correct method. Here is my structure of block code

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = 
                (SessionFactory) ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getAttribute(HibernateListener.KEY_NAME);
        Session hibernatesession = sessionFactory.openSession();
        try {
            hibernatesession.beginTransaction();
            // my database access will be here
            hibernatesession.getTransaction().commit();
            hibernatesession.flush();
            }
        catch(Exception e){
          hibernatesession.getTransaction().rollback();
          e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
          hibernatesession.close();
        }
```

This is the structure that i have created for all my dao class functions, but now my website is loading very slowly. So my questions is the stricture i have used is a correct one. Is the above code causes to open multiple session hibernate at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not good design to do transaction management in a DAO class. I would warmly recommend using Spring and its declarative transaction management, which is a breeze to set up and a no-brainer to use. If that is not available to you, then you should at least make a poor man's alternative. One suggestion is to make each DAO a subclass of a class that has a method that does the boilerplate part (session open/close, transaction begin/commit) and calls out to an overridable method to do the real work. This would implement the *Template* pattern for your scenario. This is an outline:

```
public abstract class DaoTemplate
{
  public void execute() {
    final Session s = ((SessionFactory) ServletActionContext.getServletContext()
        .getAttribute(HibernateListener.KEY_NAME)).openSession();
    try {
      s.beginTransaction();
      doTheRealStuff();
      s.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      s.getTransaction().rollback();
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally { s.close(); }
  }

  protected abstract void doTheRealStuff();
}
```

Another suggestion, and something I actually used on a project ten years ago, is to implement the *Strategy* pattern. In that case you'd pass an object to `execute` that implements the method `doTheRealStuff`. Also, in that case the `DaoTemplate` class could be a singleton (a different name for the class would be appropriate then).

Answer (score 1):

The `flush()` after the `commit()` is useless.

Do you really need to open a new session and then close it for each of your operations?

You can use `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` and `Hibernatesession.disconnect()`.